# Django how to test model functions with validator

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models, django-testing

My `models.py` is looking like this:

```
def validate_yearofbirth(value):
    text = str(value)
    if len(text) < 4 or len(text) > 4 or value < 1900:
        raise ValidationError('Please insert your year of birth!')

class Personal(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    yearofbirth = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators = [validate_yearofbirth], null = True)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.lastname, self.firstname)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

    @property
    def age(self):
        year = datetime.now().year
        age = year - self.yearofbirth
        return age
```

Anyone know how to write a test for `def validate_yearofbirth` and for `def age`? I only managed to write a test for `def fullname`, but I haven't figured out how to write a test for a function which is not `def __str__(self)`.

My `test_models.py` file for this class is looking like this:

```
class TestModel(TestCase):

    def test_personal_str(self):
        fullname = Personal.objects.create(nachname = 'Last Name', vorname = 'First Name')

        self.assertEqual(str(fullname), 'Last Name, First Name')
```

Also you can ignore the fact that `return age` doesn't always return the "real" age - this isn't important for my class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Personal

class TestPersonalModel(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Personal.objects.create(lastname = 'Schuhmacher', firstname = 'Michael', yearofbirth=1969)

    def test_fullname(self):
        person = Personal.objects.get(lastname="Schuhmacher")
        self.assertEqual(person.fullname, 'Schuhmacher, Michael')
    
    def test_age(self):
        person = Personal.objects.get(lastname="Schuhmacher")
        self.assertEqual(person.age, 52)

    def test_year_of_birth_validator(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            Personal.objects.create(lastname = 'Einstein', firstname = 'Albert', yearofbirth=1879)
```

Comment: we are expecting a ValidationError if `yearofbirth` < 1900. For some reason this Error is not raised and therefore the unit test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Michael's answer: in order for you to test validation, you need to call the object's full_clean method. Django does not validate a model when the object is saved.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    
def test_year_of_birth(self):
        obj = Personal.objects.create(lastname = 'Einstein', firstname = 'Albert', yearofbirth = 1879)
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, obj.full_clean)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722507) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this hope it will work for you

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    
def test_year_of_birth(self):
        person = Personal.objects.create(lastname = 'Einstein', firstname = 'Albert', yearofbirth = 1879)
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, person.full_clean)
```